# Prevent kids from "accidentally" making purchases in Steam

Tags: steam

The kids play with the gaming computer, which has a Steam account always logged in.

I'm worried about them "accidentally" purchasing something in the store, is there way to require a password to complete a purchase in Steam?

Comment: The better option may be to ensure it doesn't automatically log in your Steam account.

Comment: Or just tell Steam to not remember your credit card information. It helps curb impulse purchases of games you never play, too :)

Comment: @Tacroy that should be an answer.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza It's not though; it sounds like bobobobo wants Steam to remember billing information, just require a password in order to use it. Whipping out your credit card is a much larger impediment to buying something than remembering the "buy stuff" password.

Comment: @Tacroy The solution is memorize your credit card numbers! Think of it as a password.

Answer (score 58):

You can use [Family View](https://help.steampowered.com/faqs/view/6B1A-66BE-E911-3D98) to restrict what your kids can do with your Steam account, including preventing them from accessing the store. This works by setting a **4-digit PIN** that is used to log in as an adult within your account.

You can enable this and configure what parts of your Steam account are off-limits by going to *Settings → Family* and clicking on *[Manage Family View](https://store.steampowered.com/parental/set)*.

[image: Family View options screenshot]

You'll want to leave the Steam store checkbox unchecked.

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer, all others are just workarounds

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.

Comment: This feature does not appear to prevent in game purchases though. It will stop your kids from buying games, but they can still buy in game coins. Mine just spent $60 on game currency by mistake :(

Answer (score 12):

You can't buy things from steam without billing information. So, I would suggest to:

1. Clear billing information in child's account and stop using it for purchases. (On the top right of the steam window, click the child's username, and choose Account Details. Under Store and Purchase History, find the saved payment method(s) and hit Delete)
2. Setup your own steam account.
3. Buy games using your own account (buy as a gift) and gift them to your kid.

This will prevent game purchases AND "in-game" purchases.

Comment: It does work properly, used it a lot. And maybe you should go and give your friends some gifts...

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness: My friends play consoles. I use steam to buy PC games. Plus I prefer to give "material" gifts instead of digital-only purchases.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option, if none of the above work, is to put the steam client into "Offline" mode. Then they can get online and play those games that are actively downloaded/installed but they can't play uninstalled games, or go to the store and buy any additional games. Family options might be a better idea though.